# Stacking elements with mousedown events leading to events not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, dom-events

On my current project I'm using element event listeners for `mousedown` to allow the elements to be dragged.

If I spawn multiple elements at the same position with these event listeners, only the top element acts on the listener. Once the top element is removed, all elements below still have no event listener in place?

What is causing this / how do I fix it?

Please see https://github.com/MattIPv4/macOSNotifJS/issues/5 for the direct bug and https://macosnotifjs.mattcowley.co.uk/ for the live code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. I was directly updating document.body which was wiping all existing event listeners. Using insertAdjecentHTML solved the issue.